Aggregate across multiple columns of different types when pivoting in pyspark
I have a melted table of the form:

+------+---------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| time | channel | value_double | value_long | value_string |
+------+---------+--------------+------------+--------------+
|    0 | A       | 1.1          | null       | null         |
|    0 | B       | null         | 1          | null         |
|    0 | C       | null         | null       | "foo"        |
|    1 | A       | 2.1          | null       | null         |
|    1 | B       | null         | 2          | null         |
|    1 | C       | null         | null       | "bar"        |
|    2 | A       | 3.1          | null       | null         |
|    2 | B       | null         | 3          | null         |
|    2 | C       | null         | null       | "foobar"     |
+------+---------+--------------+------------+--------------+

And I'd like to pivot this table to be:
+------+-----+---+----------+
| time | A   | B | C        |
+------+-----+---+----------+
| 0    | 1.1 | 1 | "foo"    |
| 1    | 2.1 | 2 | "bar"    |
| 2    | 3.1 | 3 | "foobar" |
+------+-----+---+----------+

I've got something along the lines of:
df.groupBy("time").pivot("channel").agg(...)

But I'm strugging to fill the agg function to aggregate across the different values. I've tried coalesce but it runs into errors because of the distinct types between the columns.
Some key points:

The three value columns have distinct types (double, long, and string)
The typing is consistent per channel
There is always one and only one value column with data per row

Is this possible with PySpark/SparkSQL?

are channels A, B, C always guaranteed to having non-null values that are all the same type?

Yes, they are. They will always have one and only one non null value of the same type

Use coalesce and first functions together.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
...
df = df.groupBy('time').pivot('channel').agg(F.first(F.coalesce('value_double', 'value_long', 'value_string')))


I run into an error using this method:
Cannot resolve "coalesce(value_long, value_double, value_string)" due to data type mismatch: Input to 'coalesce' should all be the same type, but it's ("BIGINT" or "DOUBLE" or "STRING")

What is your spark version?

I'm on spark 3.4.3

Breaking down the steps for better understanding :
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, coalesce


# Identifying the appropriate value column for each channel:
df = df.withColumn("value", 
                   when(col("channel") == "A", col("value_double"))
                   .when(col("channel") == "B", col("value_long"))
                   .otherwise(col("value_string")))
                  )

# Then, pivot the DataFrame:
df_pivoted = df.groupBy("time").pivot("channel").agg(first("value"))

df_pivoted.show()

EDIT : leveraging  dynamic schema inference and data type conversion as the number of channels  are high and mapping is not efficient.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, coalesce, to_date, to_timestamp, to_timestamp_ntz


# Define a function to dynamically infer the appropriate data type:
def infer_data_type(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                return to_date(value)
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    return to_timestamp(value)
                except ValueError:
                    return to_timestamp_ntz(value)
                except ValueError:
                    return str(value)

# Create a UDF for the data type inference:
infer_type_udf = udf(infer_data_type)

# Pivot the DataFrame, inferring the data type for each value:
df_pivoted = df.groupBy("time").pivot("channel").agg(first(infer_type_udf("value")))


In reality, I have hundreds of channels and don't have a mapping of type. I'm hoping to be able to do this without creating that map. Also, I'm not sure I could create this new column because it be of different types.

I see, I now updated the answer to dynamically inference the datatypes and then use UDF for data conversion.

If it is guaranteed that there is one non-null value for each channel and each value you could restructure the DataFrame before pivoting:
df_filtered = []

for value_col in ["value_double","value_long","value_string"]:
    df_filtered.append(df.select("time","channel",value_col).dropna().groupby("time").pivot("channel").agg(F.max(value_col)))

for i, df_curr in enumerate(df_filtered):
    if i == 0:
        df_all = df_curr
    else:
        df_all = df_all.join(df_curr, on=['time'], how='inner')

Result:
+----+---+---+------+
|time|  A|  B|     C|
+----+---+---+------+
|   1|2.1|  2|   bar|
|   2|3.1|  3|foobar|
|   0|1.1|  1|   foo|
+----+---+---+------+


Use colRegex to dynamically identify the value_ like columns, then create a mapping (m) from the value columns
cols = df.select(df.colRegex(r'`value_.*`')).columns
m = F.create_map(*[y for c in cols for y in (F.lit(c), F.col(c))])
df1 = df.select('time', 'channel', m.alias('m'))

# df1.show()
# +----+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |time|channel|m                                                                   |
# +----+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |0   |A      |{value_double -> 1.1, value_long -> null, value_string -> null}     |
# |0   |B      |{value_double -> null, value_long -> 1.0, value_string -> null}     |
# |0   |C      |{value_double -> null, value_long -> null, value_string -> "foo"}   |
# |1   |A      |{value_double -> 2.1, value_long -> null, value_string -> null}     |
# |1   |B      |{value_double -> null, value_long -> 2.0, value_string -> null}     |
# |1   |C      |{value_double -> null, value_long -> null, value_string -> "bar"}   |
# |2   |A      |{value_double -> 3.1, value_long -> null, value_string -> null}     |
# |2   |B      |{value_double -> null, value_long -> 3.0, value_string -> null}     |
# |2   |C      |{value_double -> null, value_long -> null, value_string -> "foobar"}|

Use map_filter to remove the null key-value pairs
df1 = df1.withColumn('m', F.map_filter('m', lambda k, v: ~F.isnull(v)))

# df1.show()
# +----+-------+--------------------------+
# |time|channel|m                         |
# +----+-------+--------------------------+
# |0   |A      |{value_double -> 1.1}     |
# |0   |B      |{value_long -> 1.0}       |
# |0   |C      |{value_string -> "foo"}   |
# |1   |A      |{value_double -> 2.1}     |
# |1   |B      |{value_long -> 2.0}       |
# |1   |C      |{value_string -> "bar"}   |
# |2   |A      |{value_double -> 3.1}     |
# |2   |B      |{value_long -> 3.0}       |
# |2   |C      |{value_string -> "foobar"}|
# +----+-------+--------------------------+

Pivot the data frame by time and channel
df1 = df1.groupBy('time').pivot('channel').agg(F.first('m'))

# df1.show()
# +----+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
# |time|A                    |B                  |C                         |
# +----+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
# |0   |{value_double -> 1.1}|{value_long -> 1.0}|{value_string -> "foo"}   |
# |1   |{value_double -> 2.1}|{value_long -> 2.0}|{value_string -> "bar"}   |
# |2   |{value_double -> 3.1}|{value_long -> 3.0}|{value_string -> "foobar"}|
# +----+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+

Use map_values to extract the value from the mapping
df1 = df1.select('time', *[F.map_values(c)[0].alias(c) for c in df2.columns[1:]])

# df1.show()
# +----+---+---+--------+
# |time|A  |B  |C       |
# +----+---+---+--------+
# |0   |1.1|1.0|"foo"   |
# |1   |2.1|2.0|"bar"   |
# |2   |3.1|3.0|"foobar"|
# +----+---+---+--------+


I get a type compatibility error:
Cannot resolve "map(value_long, value_long, value_double, value_double, value_string, value_string)" due to data type mismatch: The given values of function 'map' should all be the same type, but they are ["BIGINT", "DOUBLE", "STRING"]. What version of pyspark will this work for?

For reference, I'm on Spark 3.4.3

I am on Spark 3.4.1

Does it still work for you if you add a value_bool column? I didn't think it was relevant to the question, but looks like it's what's causing an issue on my end.
